# Custom Layer Keras: transform output at certain positions

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I am trying to write a custom layer in Keras (with tensorflow backend) that makes certain positions binary.

For example suppose that I have [0.6,0.8,0.9,0.2] and that position 1 and 3 must be binary, I would like to have a layer that outputs [0.6,1,0.9,0]

e.g. output[pos] > 0.5 then output[pos] = 1, else output[pos] = 0

I wrote this but it is not working at all...

```
...Layers of the net...
x = Lambda(self.adjust_positions)(x)
```

here the functions I wrote

```
    def update_1(self, x, pos):
        with tf.control_dependencies([tf.assign(x[pos],[1])]):
                return tf.identity(x)

    def update_0(self, x, pos):
        with tf.control_dependencies([tf.assign(x[pos],[0])]):
                return tf.identity(x)

    def adjust_positions(self, x):
        for pos in indexes:
            tf.cond(tf.gather(x, pos)<[0.5], self.update_0(x, pos), self.update_1(x,pos))
        return x
```

The error I get is:

```
ValueError: Sliced assignment is only supported for variables
     55     def update_0(self, x, pos):
---> 56         with tf.control_dependencies([tf.assign(x[pos],[0])]):
     57                 return tf.identity(x)
```

How can I implement this functionality? What I have done is reasonable?